# Can I be charged for a transaction that I cancel on MasterCard SecureCode enabled site?

Tags: credit-card, fraud, mastercard

I have a question about a transaction that "happened" to me a few days ago.

I was buying flight tickets on a page that had a Mastercard SecureCode sign next to credit card fields - mytrip.com

1. After I entered my details I was taken to the authentication page by Swedbank where I saw a different amount (+47€ CC fees).
2. Then I canceled the authentication process by clicking "cancel". That means I don't want to buy the tickets and therefore do not authorize this payment.
3. A few minutes later I received the tickets on my email and I realized that the transaction went through. The amount of 911.50€ was booked from my bank account
4. When I contacted the merchant they told me that if the SecureCode authentication fails they use another gateway to (secretly) finalize the payment. The second gateway is not using SecureCode authentication.

I find this illegal as in the MasterCard SecureCode rules there is a note that if a website has SecureCode enabled, you can't get billed unless you authenticate yourself.

The vendor claims that this is how they work and it's my fault. As the airline is not going to refund the tickets to them, they are not going to refund to me.

Another issue is that they claim that this whole process was, in theory, a single transaction, that they have two gateways running simultaneously and if one (with the SecureCode enabled) fails they're automatically using another one (with no SecureCode authentication needed).

To me, it sounds more like two transactions and in this case the second one was not authorized by me and is therefore a misusage of my credit card details or even a fraud.

**The total amount of 911.50€ has already been removed from my account.**

The payment was made using a Mastercard debit card.

From Bank's T&C related to Mastercard SecureCode:

> ... If you are unable to provide your SecureCode or hint response, or if the
>   authentication through MasterCard SecureCode otherwise fails, the merchant may not accept
>   your credit card in payment for that transaction.

[image: Screenshot of the actual credit card fields and SecureCode badge]

Comment: Was this a credit or debit card?

Comment: It was a Mastercard debit card

Comment: The argument that the airline is not refunding them has nothing to do with you. Don't even mention it further.

Comment: So, "the merchant _may_ not accept your credit card", or they _may_ accept it, which they did. The merchant chooses. It does not say "the merchant is prevented from accepting your credit card."

Answer (score 7):

Your only recourse is to attempt to cancel the tickets through mytrip.com, and if they do not cancel the tickets, you can initiate a charge-back on your card on the grounds that they did not disclose the full price of the ticket before you initiated checkout and they did not allow you to cancel the transaction after they did disclose the price of the tickets.

You can also contact any relevant consumer protection agencies that have jurisdiction where you live.

Comment: But the fact that they were (secretly) using a non-SecureCode gateway although they stated that they do, doesn't matter at all? I mean shouldn't I get it sorted with bank and Mastercard?

Comment: The vendor said that that is the way it works in their system. When Mastercard SecureCode authentication fails they are automatically using another (non-SecureCode) gateway.

Comment: Yes, as they said that from their side it's my own fault. And that the airline is not going to refund the tickets to them and therefore they're not going to pay for it either.

Comment: @SilverRingvee, the second part of the first sentence of my answer says to initiate a charge-back. You might also want to edit your question to specifically state that the company has already completely refused to reimburse you.

Comment: @SilverRingvee If you do initiate a charge-back you may need to do it on two different charges - FAQ on the website: (http://www.mytrip.com/en/misc/faq/)

35. When will my credit card be charged?

Your credit card will be charged at the moment of the completion of your reservation. It is possible that you will note 2 different charges on your credit card, one from the airline representing the price of the ticket and another one from our company (E-Travel Athens) representing the services charge. The sum of these two charges suggest the final price of the ticket displayed on our website.

Comment: @EdHunter or just charge-back the service charge since no service was actually added. :)

Comment: What I saw on the MasterCard site says that problems with SecureCode should be discussed with the issuing bank.  You could contact your bank and try to find a way to report the merchant's misuse of the SecureCode logo.  There doesn't appear to be a specific category for this on the MasterCard reporting website, but you could also submit a complaint there (maybe under some other category) or otherwise try to get in contact with MasterCard.  The thing is that doing this may not help you get a speedy solution to your case; it will just result in the merchant being monitored more closely.

Comment: Well, I am not looking for a speedy solution anymore. For starters, I'd like to hear that my CC details were misused and I have the rights to get it refunded. Currently, I've started a credit card payment dispute with my bank but this is an extremely slow process, just an answer takes up to 60 days.

Comment: @SilverRingvee going by the MasterCard merchant handling rules, a vendor is required to attempt to authorise a transaction via SecureCode but they are not prevented from submitting the transaction after a failed SecureCode authentication - SecureCode is simply a liability shifting mechanism, whereby the liability for fraud etc is shifted from the vendor to the issuing bank.  If a vendor chooses not to use it, the liability is not shifted, but there is absolutely and utterly nothing in the rules which prevent them from not using it.  Your card details weren't misused in this instance.

Comment: So you are saying that for a customer the SecureCode badge doesn't mean anything? Even if I forget my details or simply cancel the authentication process the merchant can still use my details on another website and finalize the payment via another transaction without asking or even informing me? I am still quite certain that canceling the authentication process should cancel that specific transaction and merchant doesn't have the rights to start another one without confirming it with the customer. @Moo

Comment: @SilverRingvee all of the 3D Secure authentication systems are voluntary only and do not prevent vendors from submitting your card details without it, as I said above all they are are a liability shifting mechanism.  All you actually need to present a "card holder not present" transaction is the PAN (the long number) and the expiry date - you can submit a perfectly acceptable transaction without even the CV2 code (the code on the signature strip).  They add nothing at all for the card holder, its all to do with who holds the liability - the vendor/merchant or the card issuer.

Comment: @SilverRingvee as to what constitutes a canceled transaction, thats entirely between you and and the vendor - at the point where SecureCode comes in, you've already given them all the details required to submit a transaction, they don't need the SecureCode at all.  Cancelling the authentication process has no legal meaning when it comes to the vendors transaction - whether they have the rights to take the details you have already entered and use them in a non-liability shifted transaction is again between you and the vendor in their T&Cs, but theres nothing inherently illegal about it.

Comment: @SilverRingvee there is nothing in law which defines a "transaction".  If you cancelled out of the authentication process then, to a vendor, that can look in some circumstances like a failure of the SecureCode system (the card issuers system didnt respond etc) and they may decide to proceed without.  That doesnt make it a second transaction.

Comment: @Moo please see the updated question. (The quote from bank's T&C)

Comment: @SilverRingvee the update doesnt change anything, as it says "may not", not "is forbidden from".  I've built many payment portals, its utterly trivial to get a non-success code from a 3D Authentication step and then to submit it as a non-3D Authenticated payment.  Like, a single line of code.  Also bear in mind that vendors don't sign up to banks for this, they sign up to merchant accounts with payment processors (SagePay etc), so what the bank T&Cs says is meaningless with regard to what terms the vendor is bound to.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54940/discussion-on-answer-by-nathan-l-can-i-be-charged-for-a-transaction-that-i-cance).